# How to get link from a tag if href or src attribute doesn't contain link

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently scraping [this link](https://www.cvent.com/venues/dubai/hotel/grand-hyatt-dubai-conference-hotel/venue-f1ea54df-124e-4ba9-a551-fb2e06175c62#) using Selenium.
I want it to go to the "Meeting Rooms" section and click on "View details," then scrape the information from the page that opens.
I've written this code, but the problem is that the "View details" link is defined as "#" and it just refers back to the main page!

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.cvent.com/venues/dubai/hotel/grand-hyatt-dubai-conference-hotel/venue-f1ea54df-124e-4ba9-a551-fb2e06175c62')
#-------------------------------------------Scroll and Show All Btn
try:
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    show_all_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".MeetingRoomsGrid__viewAllToggleContainer___2HJRU button")))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(show_all_button).click().perform()
    time.sleep(5)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,TimeoutException):
    pass
title=[]
view_details=driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.MeetingRoomsGrid__venueDetailWrapper___3XYYx a')
for l in view_details:
    driver.get(l.get_attribute('href'))
    title.append(l.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'MeetingRoomDetailPage__meetingRoomNameText___3k-3T').text)
print(title)
#rest of the code
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is not rendered inside `a` tag, link is rendered inside one of scripts that is loaded during page render.

Link for rooms is builder via pattern `{url}/meetingRoom-{roomId}`

`id`s can be found via parsing `script` tag by pattern `{"id":"([^"]+)"`

So, your steps are:

1. Get needed script element
2. Unescape script for easier readability
3. Get it's `innerText` property
4. Split script text via `badges` object (so only rooms ids would be in first part of array)
5. Apply pattern `{"id":"([^"]+)"` to extract ids
6. Construct url, using pattern `{url}/meetingRoom-{match}`

```py
import re
import html
# your imports

url="https://www.cvent.com/venues/dubai/hotel/grand-hyatt-dubai-conference-hotel/venue-f1ea54df-124e-4ba9-a551-fb2e06175c62"
driver.get(url)

script = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//script[contains(.,'{&quot;id&quot;')]")))

pattern = r'{"id":"([^"]+)"'
script_text = html.unescape(script.get_property('innerText'))
matches = re.findall(pattern, script_text.split('"badges"')[0])

for match in matches:
    meeting_room = f"{url}/meetingRoom-{match}"
    print(meeting_room)
```

Comment: That was fantastic! Yes, it worked, and I really appreciate your help. It was a big assistance.

Comment: Is it possible for you to take a look at this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77377085/chrome-web-driver-dont-show-element

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the '#' in the href attribute is essentially a placeholder and does not lead to a new page or trigger any navigation action. This is a common technique used when you want to trigger JavaScript functionality without causing a page reload or navigation.

You need to update the code to generate a link when each 'View details' link is clicked and store it in a list. The generated link is fixed and not change after each click so allowing you to use them for subsequent steps.

You can find the code as below:

```
driver.get('https://www.cvent.com/venues/dubai/hotel/grand-hyatt-dubai-conference-hotel/venue-f1ea54df-124e-4ba9-a551-fb2e06175c62')
#-------------------------------------------Scroll and Show All Btn
try:
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    show_all_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".MeetingRoomsGrid__viewAllToggleContainer___2HJRU button")))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(show_all_button).click().perform()
    time.sleep(2)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException,TimeoutException):
    pass
title=[]
time.sleep(3)

meetingroom_grid=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//a[@class="MeetingRoomsGrid__meetingRoomLink___3aOZn"]')

for i in range(len(meetingroom_grid)):
    
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",meetingroom_grid[i])
    time.sleep(4)    
    ### Adding your code for extracting the required data ###
    print ("Meeting room name: ",driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[@class="MeetingRoomDetailPage__meetingRoomNameText___3k-3T"]').text,' url: ',driver.current_url)
    back_to_main=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[@class="MeetingRoomDetailPage__backToVenueLink___3v4-m"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",back_to_main)
    time.sleep(4)    
    meetingroom_grid=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//a[@class="MeetingRoomsGrid__meetingRoomLink___3aOZn"]')    
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, that's right. But there is no button element for click in html structure…

Comment: @AAghighi look at my answer below. It is possible, however, a bit complicated.

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your requirement, please check it.

Comment: @Goodi I really appreciate your help, you've been very kind. I just have one question.

This code gives the answer as long as i is less than nine, but for higher values of i, it doesn't give an answer because it has to press the "Show All" button again.

I came up with the idea of clicking the "Show All" button in this case and continuing, but it takes a lot of time to execute the code this way.

Do you have any solution?

Thanks again.