# chrome web driver don't show element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Based on my previous post on this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284289/how-to-get-link-from-a-tag-if-href-or-src-attribute-doesnt-contain-link) and with help of @Yaroslavm,I wrote this code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url='https://www.cvent.com/venues/en-US/dubai/hotel/grand-hyatt-dubai-conference-hotel/venue-f1ea54df-124e-4ba9-a551-fb2e06175c62?aCode=X5NLCVLZTCV&filter=eJyrrgUAAXUA-Q&geo=eJx9UF1rwjAU_Sslz66kaZKmvtWPiQ_qQGW-SdpGG0gTSVNQpP99ycZ0IOzpwrnn4557BydjW-6cqLeC26rZiasDYzDrSy6jt2ivpV9FheVlNG-l5U50YASkhyVXC2HOll8aWb1L5YT1wslmv54t14vjZHPwxNL0upb6PDHXX8oduNtF_EsNJG2sa-a8cx9GahcQxf1AJE4JIxRSiijJGR0BZTQYExITiglKSIZwAhEdRqAzvWs-xYsFjrM8xQwnjOQQ4YcFjlkOMcEpIjCHEA-DNzk_On67vLRYFYflar86zpbbXbGezn2Tll9l27dgnLzI__ZA0N-Qp88CKIMZQyykVkafZC2CwNleBKDXzt6mpg6hRYjp_LOUKOraiq7b_VyjTMWVdDcwfAG8RJXo&sort=CVENT_PICKS&view=LIST#MEETING_SPACE'
driver.get(url)
script = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//script[contains(.,'{&quot;id&quot;')]")))
pattern = r'{"id":"([^"]+)"'
script_text = html.unescape(script.get_property('innerText'))
links = re.findall(pattern, script_text.split('"badges"')[0])
roomlinks = []
for l in links:
    substring = url[:url.find("?")]
    roomlinks.append(f"{substring}/meetingRoom-{l}")
    room_list = []
    for link in roomlinks[1:3]:
        print(link)
        driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(10)
        roomAmenitiesVar = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                            'h5.MeetingRoomDetailPage__amenityListTitle___1jM5Q')
        roomAmenitiesAm = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                   'div.Grid__col___gBFRS.MeetingRoomDetailPage__amenityList___3XlFG.Grid__col-xs-12___2eswl.Grid__col-xs-offset-0___aTK-4.Grid__col-sm-6___CaUu-.Grid__col-sm-offset-0___tTaDk.Grid__col-md-offset-0___2SImQ.Grid__col-lg-offset-0___Atw2J ul')
        roomAmenities = {}
        for v, a in zip(roomAmenitiesVar, roomAmenitiesAm):
            roomAmenities[v.text] = a.text
print(roomAmenities)
```

But when driver open the room link don't show Amenities part on the page! While there is Amenities part on the link.

Comment: Looks like a bug on your resource. Try to go to that link manually via site (Amenties would be displayed) and then refresh page via browser -> amenties would disappear, 'Other' would be shown.

Comment: You can write to their support and report that amenities are disappeared after page refresh. (Explain that you opened some of them, then lost internet connection, pages are refreshed and amenities are disappeared, blah, blah)

Comment: Proof: https://monosnap.com/file/Htk69bRoxTmqUesc02FrLLMbS8iUAr

You can send this video to their support.

Comment: Yes! that's true. I wanted to make sure that the code I wrote doesn't have any issues.